# Interaction between client and server using ajax and json response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website, that I am building that allows consumers to order food. The user will search by their Postal code (UK) such as A1 1AA for example. Once they search by their postal code, the restaurants that deliver to their area will appear.

I am currently working on the checkout page, and i want to stop users from inputting a postal code that, that said restaurant does not deliver too. I would like to do this the moment the user presses enter on the postal code field.

I just have no idea how to do this, i have put together some ajax following a number of posts (see below,very first time using ajax so please forgive me if its sloppy) to do this,i know it is not complete but i have no idea where to go from here.

I have a string url with the users area and postal code, within it. and i also have a database with the postal codes the restaurants delivers to, i would like to do something along the lines of if the restaurant does not deliver to the postal code entered echo "Sorry, This restaurant does not deliver to A1. ".

I have tried to achieve this using both AJAX and Jquery

**Code**

```
<div id="container">
 <form id="myform" name='myForm'>
    <input type="text" id='doorno' name="doorno" value="" placeholder="e.g. 2a" min="1" >
   <input type="text" id='addlin1' name="addlin1" value="" placeholder="e.g. Brunel Hall">
  <input type="text" id='addlin2' name="addlin2" value="" ><br>
  <input type="text" id='city' name="city" value="" >

  <input type="text" id='postal' name="postal" value="" placeholder=""><br>
</form>


<div id='ajaxDiv' style="background-color:red">Your result will display here</div>

$(function() {
  $("#container").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
  e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the default action of a enter 
    $.post('ajax-example.php',$("#myform").serialize() ,  function(response) { 
  $('#ajaxDiv').html(response); // this will echo any response from ajax file
       });
     }   
  });
});
```

I have just tried it in Jquery. It work almost perfectly apart from it doesn't work on keypress but onclick, but i don't know how i would do something along the lines of if $_POST['postal'] is not equal to $postcode( users postcode variable from string url)/ the postcodes the restaurant delivers to column in my db

```
$(function(){

$('input[name="postal"]').click(function(){
 alert('Hello...!');
 });

$('#city').keypress(function (e) {
var key = e.which;
  if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
     {
$('input[name = postal]').click();
     return false;  
         }
     });

});
```

Comment: @SachinDivakar what you have said, as confused me. but i hope i answer your query i am trying to get whatever the user inputs to catch with what is in the db. But i don't know how to do it using jQuery or ajax.

Comment: your approach is correct but before that I want to knolw one thing why do you want to use #container for .keypress() function when actually you want is  input[name="postal "] selector in first program

Comment: @SachinDivakar i think these are just little mistakes I've been making, find of teaching myself, by reading plenty and looking at posts. I noticed that after i had posted it, but was hoping it wouldn't course a big issue

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery; You may want to try this approach and see if it does what you want:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){


            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    if($(":focus").get(0) == $('input[name = postal]').get(0) ){
                        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO HERE
                        // BECAUSE ENTER WAS PRESSED INSIDE OF THE FIELD WITH THE NAME postal
                        // FOR TESTING... ALERT SOMETHING...
                        alert("Sure, you pressed the Enter Key inside of the Postal Field...");
                    }
                }
            });

            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

You can test and Fiddle it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/csqsLmxh/

OK, so here's how it all ties together.

**JAVASCRIPT: JQUERY**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){


            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    if($(":focus").get(0) == $('input[name = postal]').get(0) ){
                        // SEND OUT AN AJAX REQUEST TO THE PHP-SCRIPT ON THE SERVER
                        // HERE WE ARE SIMPLY SAYING:
                        // ONCE THE USER FINISHES TYPING INSIDE THE POSTAL FIELD & HITS ENTER
                        // GO TO THE SERVER AND ASK THE SCRIPT: ajax.processor.php TO USE THE
                        // POSTED POSTAL CODE & CITY TO SEARCH FOR THE NEAREST AVAILABLE RESTAURANT...
                        // IN THIS CASE WE USE JSON, JUST IN CASE WE MAY WANT TO SEND BACK A COLLECTION OF DATA...
                        // AND SO OUR AJAX GOES LIKE THIS:
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "./ajax-processor.php",
                            dataType: "json",    //<== CHANGE TO "HTML" IF YOU ARE EXPECTING HTML DATA.
                            cache: false,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ({
                                postal  : $("#postal").val(),
                                city    : $("#city").val()
                            }),

                            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                // IF OUR AJAX CALL SUCCEEDS AND THUS RETURNS SOME RESULTS
                                // IN THIS CASE JSON, WE CAN USE IT TO UPDATE THE #ajaxDiv...
                                // HOWEVER IF WE ARE EXPECTING JUST HTML WE WILL GO A DIFFERENT ROUTE IN THE SUCCESS HANDLER...
                                // PLEASE, NOTE THAT YOU MAY NOT HAVE BOTH JSON & HTML SIMULTANEOUSLY
                                // THIS IS AN "EITHER-OR" CASE HERE:
                                // SO IF YOU EXPECT HTML, YOU ARE ADVISED TO 
                                // EITHER DELETE OR COMMENT-OUT FROM THE BEGINNING 
                                // TO THE END OF JSON HANDLING LOGIC BELOW & VICE-VERSA
                                if(data){
                                    // ##BEGINNING OF JSON HANDLING...## //
                                    if(data.restaurant){
                                        var output = "<em>Restaurant: </em><strong>" + data.restaurant + "</strong>"; 
                                        output    += "<br /><em>Take-Away: </em><strong>" + data.takeAway + "</strong>"; 
                                        $("#ajaxDiv").html(output );
                                    }
                                    // ## END OF JSON HANDLING... ## //

                                    // ##BEGINNING OF HTML HANDLING...## //
                                        $("#ajaxDiv").html(data);  <== JUST UPDATE THE DIV WITH THE RAW DATA FROM THE RESPONSE... IT IS EITHER HTML OR STRING OR NUMERIC DATA...
                                    // ##END OF HTML HANDLING...## //
                                }
                            },

                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                            },

                            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="myform" name='myForm'>
            <input type="text" id='doorno' name="doorno" value="" placeholder="e.g. 2a" min="1" >
            <input type="text" id='addlin1' name="addlin1" value="" placeholder="e.g. Brunel Hall">
            <input type="text" id='addlin2' name="addlin2" value="" ><br>
            <input type="text" id='city' name="city" value="" >
            <input type="text" id='postal' name="postal" value="" placeholder=""><br>
        </form>


        <div id='ajaxDiv' style="background-color:red">Your result will display here</div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php

        // FILENAME: ajax-processors.php        <== MUST MATCH THE URL WE DECLARED IN THE AJAX DEFINITION (JS)
        $postal     = isset($_POST['postal'])   ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['postal']))  : null;
        $city       = isset($_POST['city'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['city']))    : null;
        // RUN YOUR QUERIES AND DO ALL YOUR MAGIC USING THE POSTED $postal & $city
        // TO DETERMINE WHICH DATA ARE RELEVANT TO BE RETURNED...
        // ASSUMING IN THE END YOUR QUERIES RETURNED SAY 2 RESULTS LIKE Derby Inn, Kings Pizza.
        // YOU CAN THEN BUNDLE THE RESULTS INTO AN ARRAY (IF IT IS NOT ALREADY AN ARRAY OR OBJECT) LIKE SO:
        $arrResponse = array(
            "restaurant"    => "Derby Inn",
            "takeAway"      => "Kings Pizza",
        );
        // HOWEVER, THIS IS NOT NECESSARY IF YOU ARE SENDING BACK ONLY A STRING VALUE... 
        // IN THE CASE OF A STRING VALUE (SAY, JUST "Kings Pizza")
        // YOU COULD JUST DO IT OTHERWISE. LIKE THIS:
        /* die("Kings Pizza"); */

        // IF YOU DID IT LIKE THIS, BE SURE TO CHANGE YOUR THE "dataType" ATTRIBUTE 
        // IN YOUR AJAX FROM *JSON* TO **HTML** AND ALSO TO HANDLE THE SUCCESS
        // CALLBACK DIFFERENTLY... ***SEE THE JAVASCRIPT SECTION FOR COMMENTS***


        // NOW WE ARE DONE... ALL WE NEED DO IS SEND THIS RESPONSE BACK TO THE SCRIPT AS JSON LIKE SO:
        die( json_encode($arrResponse));

        // ALTHOUGH THERE ARE NO REAL QUERIES HERE OR ANY PROCESSING LOGIC, 
        // THIS SCRIPT WILL STILL RUN & SEND BACK JSON DATA TO THE JAVASCRIPT 
        // DOUBT IT? THEN TRY IT....
```

Comment: Thank you. much appreciated. But is there any way to process a query like you would in php with jquery

Comment: Yes.... 100%! Via ajax.... so what you want is: ***when someone hits enter on the postal field, a query is run to fetch results from the server (php/mysql) right?***

Comment: Yes that is correct, very new to this and have been looking everywhere

Comment: @Blue  The code has now been updated to reflect your use case. Try it out and let us know how it all plays out...   Cheers   ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try this right now. was just reading through it trying to gain a understanding. on the ajax-processors.php is there any need to redirect the page back to the page the page with the form on it?

Comment: @Blue    There is nothing else to do... the part of PHP that reads ***die(...)*** takes care of handing the JSON Data back to Javascript which will be used to update your <div> Element. Otherwise, you have nothing anymore to do. That is the beauty of AJAX. However, make sure you just do it as described in the comments. For this case, ***the ajax-processor.php File must be in the same directory as the Main File containing the HTML Markup*** otherwise, AJAX wouldn't find it...

Comment: @Blue   By the way; if your Javascript Code lives in a separate File, please be sure to ***remove all the <script ...></script> Tags, else it won't work.*** But, **assuming the Javascript live on the same File as the HTML File that holds your Form, You must leave them there**. Either ways, ***You must include the JQuery Library... whether from your Local System or from any CDN.***

Comment: Okay amazing. i think i may need to learn AJAX properly after this. Just writing my query

Comment: Please... in the Javascript... on the the $.ajax section: Try changing the url to **"./ajax-processor.php"**

Comment: sorry last question, you see the array. if that needed if different postcodes may be called each time

Comment: Okay ill do that now

Comment: sorry is the array needed. i ask as i would have to manually input the data. and there is about 100 different postal codes in my website. So the different postcodes may be called each time a user inputs as postcode into the postal field

Comment: No.... You read the comments... The Array is only needed when you want to send back a collection as opposed to a scalar.  so now I will change this again to reflect a scalar rather than a collection. However; **it could help a lot if you just showed me your PHP code** so i can see where you are headed. You can ***go to: http://eval.in and paste your PHP code, then copy the URL from the Address bar and paste it here*** so I can have a look...

Comment: @Blue Comments have been added to the codes to help you see the differences between using JSON or Raw HTML/Normal String...

Comment: @Blue    Do you have Skype? I your code and I spotted your Problem now.... it wouldn't take more than a few minutes....

Comment: @Blue     Go to https://eval.in/571923  That would be the code you are looking for but still i need more information like: **WHAT IS THE NAME OF YOUR TABLE? WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE COLUMN YOU ARE LOOKING FOR INSIDE THE TABLE ?**

Comment: Hi, sorry i feel asleep. No i don't have Skype but i can make one if need be

Comment: Name of my table is Delivery_Pcode, the column is Pcode

Comment: Sure, I'd just like to help... that's why I asked if you've got skype... it makes things easier... you can make one so that we can solve it together, ok? That would be ideal... By the way; ***if the Name of your table is Delivery_Pcode, and the column is Pcode, then the code here:*** https://eval.in/571923 ***is right...*** so let me know once you got skype up and running so we can pin-point the bug together, ok?

Comment: I am just downloading the app now

Comment: Okay great.. speak to you then

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, here you are trying to add a keypress handler on the input field.
This handler will make a post request and will validate whether deliver is possible in the specified postal code.
If that's the case  then it would be better to use blur handler instead of keypress.
Because keypress will trigger server request for every key pressed, i.e. if user enters 5 digit postal code e.g. AA110 then 5 times post request will be sent which is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Great! but is there anyway to compare the user input to what in the db or in my url string.

Comment: Oh@Blue it can be done using several methods you can use the parameter in php page compare it with data there and return true or false information as response and inside callback function you can check if its true or false

Comment: @SachinDivakar i know this is cheeky of me to ask, but do you have a example at all

Comment: So what does the php page do and in what format does that data is returned

Answer (score 0):

After talking to you what I understood is that you have successfully done

1. On pressing enter you sent a query to database
2. Then from database you sent process it and send error message if postal codes do not match
3. Now you want to know .howt to process no delivery error message sent from database  inside the post callback function so as to provide alert or notification to user 
   For that purpose I have put down a small example 
   create two files `Example.php` and `Example.html` in root directory and copy  each of the files content from here to inside them now in browser type 
   `localhost/Example.html`press enter notice each time you run the file the output changes.

Data from php to html page is sent using `json` format which will be useful to you in future a lot.First data to be sent is inserted into an associative array
then it is encode into json format using json_encode() function in server side 
`JSON.parse()` method is used to parse the json format data obtained here the value of json object is accessed using `jsonobjectname.keyName` to get the value sent from server.

Here in case

```
var returned = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(returned.Key);
```

these lines explains it

And by the way when associative array is converted into json format it looks like this

```
$result = array("Key"=>"1");
echo json_encode($result);
{"Key":"1"}
```

[Here is document of json_encode function](http://nz.php.net/json_encode)

Another thing I used random variable generator function rand() to simulate both true and false conditions for the loop .

**Example.php**

```
<?php 
$trueorfalse = rand(0, 1);
if($trueorfalse){//your condition if there is delivery
$result = array("Key"=>"1");
echo json_encode($result);
}else{//your condition if there is no delivery
$result = array("Key"=>"0");
echo json_encode($result);
}

?>
```

**Example.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("/NTD.php",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var returned = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(returned.Key);

        if(returned.Key==0){
         $("#NotifcationDiv").html("There is no shipping to your region");
        alert(returned["Key"]+"No delivery");

}
        })

        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="NotifcationDiv"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Disclaimer:Sorry for being late I saw the OP question and worded a simple example of json and php interaction from server to client and I only so the another answer posted down later only

Comment: Thank you, have only just seen this myself, will try and grasp and understanding then apply

Comment: @Blue I saw your comment three hours late .What was different and confusing about your question was nobody reading would not find error in it .And what you actually wanted was never asked in question which I found only after reading last comment as you wanted example on how to communicate between server and client and how servers echo can be checked at client side and on basis of that how the decision can be taken and one more thing try to upvote the things you find as helpful answer and accept the most helpful one .Its one of the basic things of the site .So that its helpful for the next guy

Comment: Do this and respond to me